# Why can dynamic libraries link to other libraries, but static ones can't?

Tags: c++, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

Consider the following code structure:

`main.cpp -> depends on libone.a -> depends on libtwo.a`

Assume that in `main.cpp` only functions from `libone.a` are used. So realistically the programmer writing `main.cpp` really only cares about `libone.a`. At this point they don't even know `libone.a` has a dependency on `libtwo.a`.

They attempt to compile their code as follows and get linker errors:

`g++ -o main main.cpp -lone`

> ### [image] -- Error! Undefined symbols!

This becomes an issue because since `libone.a` depends on `libtwo.a`, anyone who uses `libone.a` must know about this dependency... As you can imagine this problem can occur with FAR more dependencies than a single library and can quickly become a linking nightmare.

---

### Attempt 1 at solving this issue:

A first thought to solve this issue was "It's simple, i'll just link `libone.a` with `libtwo.a` when I compile `libone.a`!

It turns out it isn't as simple as I had hoped... When compiling `libone.a` there is no way to link `libtwo.a`. Static libraries don't link to anything when you compile them, instead all of the dependencies must be linked when the libraries are compiled into an executable.

For example, to compile `main.cpp` that depends on a static library that in turn depends on another static library, you must link both libraries. ALWAYS.

`g++ -o main main.cpp -lone -ltwo`

---

### Attempt 2 at solving this issue:

Another thought was to try and compile `libone` as a dynamic library that links to `libtwo.a`.

Oddly enough this just worked! After compiling and linking `libone.so` the main program only needs to care about `libone.so` and doesn't need to know about `libtwo.a` anymore.

`g++ -o main main.cpp -lone`

> ### Success!

---

After going through this exercise one piece is still missing. I just can't seem to figure out any reason why static libraries can't link in other libraries, but dynamic ones can.  As a matter of fact, the dynamic library, `libone.so` would not compile at all until I linked `libtwo.a`. That's fine though, because as the author of `libone.so` I would know about its dependency on `libtwo.a` - The author of `main.cpp`, however would not know. And realistically they should not have to know.

*So down to the real question... Why can dynamic libraries link to other libraries like this while static ones cannot? This seems to be an obvious advantage dynamic libraries have over static ones, but I've never seen it mentioned anywhere!*

Comment: Re: "At this point they don't even know libone.a has a dependency on libtwo.a." -- then they have failed to do their job. Choosing software components requires **understanding** what they do and how they do it, **including** any other components that they depend on.

Comment: @PeteBecker, what happens when "libtwo.a" depends on "libthree.a" that depends on "libx.a", "liby.a" and "libz.a" .... and those depend on other libraries. Requiring knowledge of all of the libraries each other library requires is just ludicrous.

Comment: That's why you need a tool like CMake that encapsulate these dependencies ;) (when you build the libraries).

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, We have that tool... unfortunately the vendor we get the software from uses "old-style" cmake - pre 2.8 - and gets none of it's dependency management capabilities... LOL *(that's a sad LOL... I'm really crying deeply inside.)*

Comment: I cry for you :(

Comment: @tjwrona1992 -- it's called "engineering". There's nothing ludicrous about it. But you've asked a good question, too: how to handle those dependencies in your build process. But you can't handle dependencies unless you know about them. And you can't ship your product without knowing about them unless you like support calls asking why your product gets a "library not found" error when your customers try to run it.

Comment: @PeteBecker, I think there may be a misunderstanding here. I'm saying the customer should not need to know about these dependencies. If the customer wants to link to one of your libraries they shouldn't have to jump through hoops to figure out what other libraries they need to link to. If CMake is configured correctly customers can import your CMake targets and not need to worry about transitive dependencies.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 -- yes, if you sell source code to customers, you are responsible for providing a build system that works. You can't do that without knowing your code's library dependencies. Why are you fighting so hard against the idea that **you**, as a **software developer**, ought to know what your code depends on?

Comment: @PeteBecker, I'm not. When you are writing your own libraries you must know what they depend on. But when you deliver these libraries to customers who will link and use them, the customer should not have to know. I am currently a customer dealing with delivered libraries where I DO have to know all of the dependencies and it is not a pleasant experience. -- and no, these dependencies are not well documented.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 The [stackoverflow tag wiki on static-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-libraries/info) may help.

Answer (score 7):

A static library is just an archive of object files, there is no concept of dependency because it was never linked.

Shared libraries are linked, solving symbols, and they can have, as such, dependencies.

Comment: So in cases where one library depends on other libraries should using a dynamic library always be the preferred approach rather than requiring programmers to link to the static library along with its dependencies?

Comment: @tjwrona1992 That's really a question of use-case. I often split my private project into multiple static libraries that are linked into the final application. Also, sometimes you *can't* use dynamic libraries (depending on target and/or library version dependencies).

Comment: In our system we have a bunch of libraries that all depend on other libraries and they're all static. It's becoming a total dependency nightmare... People literally link through trial and error...

Comment: Also I kind of get what your answer is saying, but it doesn't really answer *why* static libraries are not linked and *why* dynamic ones are. Why do dynamic libraries need to be linked?

Comment: @tjwrona1992 Think of dynamic libraries as a special kind of program, one that you can't run but it's still loaded by the OS like one. Especially on POSIX systems (like e.g. Linux). And as the updated answer now says, static libraries are just a collection of unlinked object files.

Comment: Shared libraries are a different beast than static libraries, it's apple and oranges. In a static libraries, you can put everything, and when you link, you just retrieve what you say you need. Shared libraries are objects that you ship and are "executed".

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, then to me it feels like it would be bad practice to write a static library that depends on another static library. Once transitive dependencies get involved static linking becomes a big mess.

Comment: Lots of people prefer static libraries because there is no loading library start-up issue, only one big executable. On some clusters, with 100s of libraries, it can be painful. I don't agree with that approach, I always developed with my computation kernels behaving as plugins, hence only shared libraries. Even on big clusters.

Answer (score 3):

Since your question refers to gcc and .so/.a files, I’ll assume you’re using some flavor of Unix that uses ELF files for object code.

> After going through this exercise one piece is still missing. I just
>   can't seem to figure out any reason why static libraries can't link in
>   other libraries, but dynamic ones can.

Static libraries are not linked, as was mentioned in another answer. They are just an archive of compiled object files. Shared libraries are in fact linked, which means the linker actually resolves all the symbols reachable by any exported symbol. Think of exported symbols as the library’s API. A fully linked shared library contains either the definition of each symbol, or the dependency information necessary to tell the OS (specifically the dynamic loader) what *other* shared libraries are needed to have access to the symbol. The linker assembles all that into a special file format called an [ELF shared object](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) (dynamic library).

> As a matter of fact, the dynamic library, libone.so would not compile
>   at all until I linked libtwo.a. That's fine though, because as the
>   author of libone.so I would know about its dependency on libtwo.a -
>   The author of main.cpp, however would not know. And realistically they
>   should not have to know.

`libone.so` probably compiles fine, but won’t link without `libtwo` due to *unresolved symbols*. Because the linker must resolve all reachable symbols when linking a shared library, it will fail if it can’t find any. Since `libone.so` uses symbols in `libtwo`, the linker needs to know about `libtwo.a` to find them. When you link a static library into a shared library, the symbols are resolved by copying the definitions directly into the output shared object file, so at this point, users of `libone.so` can be none the wiser about its usage of `libtwo` since its symbols are just in `libone.so`.

The other option is to link shared libraries into other shared libraries. If you are linking `libtwo.so` into `libone.so` (note the .so suffix), then the linker resolves the symbols needed by `libone` by adding a special section to the output shared object file that says it needs `libtwo.so` at runtime. Later, when the OS loads `libone.so`, it knows it also needs to load `libtwo.so`. And, if your application only uses `libone` directly, that’s all you need to tell the linker at build time, since it’ll link in `libone`, see that it needs `libtwo`, and recursively resolve until everything is good.

Now, all that loading at runtime the OS has to do incurs a performance cost, and there are some gotchas with global static variables that exist in multiple shared objects if you aren’t careful. There are some other potential performance benefits for linking statically that I won’t go into here, but suffice it to say that using dynamic libraries isn’t quite as performant on average, but that difference is also negligible for most real world situations.